# Issue with passing data from middleware

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I have been trying to wrap my head around passing data with middleware using the request and response objects in Express.js, and for some reason the data is getting stuck in a callback function in the middleware itself.

First off, here's the custom middleware:

```
// Get list of admins
export var listAdmins = function(req, res, next) {
  var admin = [];

  client.admins.list((res) => {
    var body = res.body.admins;
    // var admin = [];

    body.forEach(function (body) {
      if (body.type === 'admin') {
        admin.push(body);
      }
    });
    req.admins = admin;
    console.log(req.admins);
    console.log('Finished fetching admin data');
    next();
  });
}
```

The *commented out console.log* within the callback function gives the exact data I want to pass, and the object passes nicely. Unfortunately if I try to grab that outside of the callback, it always comes up as undefined. I moved the admin array object outside of the callback thinking it was a scope issue, but it did not solve anything.

Since this is a function that calls a function from an API, I'm guessing that is contributing to my problem. I want to reuse many of these functions, but if it is the reason for the issue of passing data, I'm all ears to suggestions. Anything to help take advantage of this framework, is highly appreciated. :)

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Yes, moving the code into the nested function block allowed for it to be set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`client.admins.list()` is *asynchronous* and returns immediately, before `req.admins` is set. Move your last three lines of code *inside* (at the end of) the callback passed to `client.admins.list()`.

Comment: Yes, I thought that was obvious, but I guess what you are trying to say is that anything expected to return must be within that function? As for it helping, the req.admins still does not leave that bit of middleware. Once the middleware is finished, the property in the request is gone, even when passing it through the next function into the next middleware.

Comment: If you're still having problems after implementing the solution I proposed, you will need to post more relevant code in your question that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: After resetting running a debug to check to see if it was getting set, it was showing outside of the middleware, so I'm guessing it was a change that babel-watch didn't apply at first. Thank you for the help.